# Specman- How can I implement a sequential coverage?

Tags: specman, test-coverage

I have an event named `tx_intrpt_e`.
I want to create the following coverage:
On tx_intrpt_e wait few cycles cross  uarttx_dma_sreq==1.

Where uarttx_dma_sreq is a port of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new event that emitted "few cycles" after the original one, and the define the cover on the new event:

```
event tx_intrpt_e;
event tx_intrpt_e_delay is {@tx_intrpt_e;[3]}@clk;

cover tx_intrpt_e_delay is {
    item uarttx_dma_sreq using ignore uarttx_dma_sreq==0;
}
```

Comment: But if the number of the cycles can be in some range, for example 1-10?